# Can I derive from IBindingList to facilitate lazy loading in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, data-binding

I'm using a class derived from IBindingList to databind a 3rd party WinForms grid to a database via NHibernate, using lazy loading.

Currently, to make lazy loading work, I need to keep an NH session open all the time, so that when the user clicks on a new row in the grid, there's a session available to load the rest of the object graph for the object selected.

However, many people suggest that this is bad practice.

So, I'm wondering if I can hook into IBindingList somehow to intercept data fetches originating from the grid, and create and discard sessions on the fly.

I quickly looked at IBindingList in the Object Browser, and the only thing that looked plausible was to override the indexer ("this [int]") in IList< T >.

Is this a viable approach, or is there a better way?

Comment: Perhaps a good starting point on session management in winforms http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874981/nhibernate-win-forms-session-management

Comment: @Vadim - thanks.  I'm aware of all this, but find it particularly opaque, for some reason.  Simple question - do you know if CBPBT will do databinding and lazy loading?

Answer (score 1):

In order to me the one you proposed is the best approach. I used it in past, and I suggest to decida a "page" size, and load in the indexer an entire page if not yet cached. Use SetMinResult, SetMaxResults to fech pages of records, and keep an undelyng dictionary of page already present. Some little hack to remember: delete all the item cached when you change sort/filters. I wrote a post about my solution here:

http://www.felicepollano.com/Trackback.aspx?guid=831f463b-f3cf-47e4-b210-b80f6c6d1b32
that is not perfect but working ;). Some more example you can find ( I think ) in the u[nofficial NHibernate addins](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/).

Comment: I checked out your blog.  Looks interesting, but the links to the source and zip files are broken.  Any other way I can get them?

Comment: did you lookm inside the unofficial nhibernate addin ?

Comment: Yes, I've been to that site a few times, but can never figure out how to get the source. What's the secret?

Comment: Also, I've looked at the Conversation per Business Transaction stuff several times too - will it allow lazy loading via databinding?